# Is it possible to trace back the "create index" statement used on a table

Tags: oracle, indexing, ddl

I want to create indices on a table. I didn't realize it will grow so fast in size that I'm not even able to select a handful of rows. Now, I want this table to be so alike another table. So I want to check the indices and the exact create index statement used on that table.

Comment: The information is all there in the data dictionary views. Using a tool like SqlDeveloper you can browse the schema and see DDL statements that would recreate the same tables and indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is to query `USER_INDEXES` table using the particular table name and get the DDL using `DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL()`

```
SELECT INDEX_NAME FROM USER_INDEXES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'MY_TABLE'

SELECT CAST(DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('INDEX','PGIT_POLICY_1') AS VARCHAR2(4000)) 
FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [SQL developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) to see the indexes of your tables and export the DDL script (including the create index) of a particular table too.